# What can I use for full scale mock-ups other than less expensive lumber?

Tags: wood, construction

We are often asked to do full scale mock-ups of proposed projects - whether a pergola, shed, or stone layout.  Clients want to see how a project will look in the space and experience the sense of an enclosed space.

Typically we use cheap lumber or plywood. What can I use for full scale mock-ups other than less expensive lumber?

Comment: For plywood you could simply use cardboard.  Actually thinking about shipping cartons I’ve received over the years it seems like you can make really sturdy supports to, unboxed a fire pit recently and it had laminated beams made of cardboard inside. Probably take some initial investment of time to familiarize yourself with what’s available and the best ways to buy large quantities.

Comment: Does it have to be wood?  can you use high density foam?

Comment: Question about why on hold: would questions about drafting plans be off topic? Questions about technique? In our world, mock-ups are a critical part of many jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric can fill in a plane to visually give a sense of volume and does not take that much space to store.  It may be worth investing in making some grommeted panels that can be reused.  Fabric sources could be cheap bedsheets, painters canvas drop cloths, or tarps.  Create a Tinker-Toy-like set of small dimension lumber pieces and fastening plates or bolts to create the structure to affix the fabric panels to.

Tarps can be walked on and can clearly show patio, walkway, and flowerbed dimensions.

I have stacked cardboard boxes to simulate a large piece of furniture I was considering purchasing to see if I wanted to live with that large object in the room.  Appliance and mattress stores may be sources for large boxes that can be broken down and re-used.

Comment: I always get “down voted” for answering questions that have been closed, but it’s closed because people have not experienced this issue. (I don’t see the difference between helping someone pick the right material for wall insulation and helping you pick the right material for construction design.) So...we use foam-core board. It’s a foam board about 1/8” thick with a hard paper covering on both sides. It’s cheap and easy to work...you can cut it with a knife, easily glued together. We find it in art stores and comes in various sizes: 16” x 24”,  18”x 30” , etc.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed.  My suggested re-phrasing to make it more general was apparently not accepted.  I think that the dilemma presented by the original question is a common one.